# Unable to send push notification to IOS from webapi?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am developing web application in webapi and creating push notification. Below problem i am facing. Whenever i write below code i am able to send messages.

```
      String payload;
                string strmsgbody = "";
                int totunreadmsg = 20;
                strmsgbody = "Hey Ashish";
 Request.SaveAs(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("APNSduringdevice.txt"), true);
                payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + strmsgbody + "\",\"badge\":" + totunreadmsg.ToString() + ",\"sound\":\"mailsent.wav\"},\"acme1\":\"bar\",\"acme2\":42}";
```

Whenever i replace strmsgbody with below code

```
string IOSmessage = "XYZ Financing" + RequestType;
            string IOScontentTitle = RequestType + " status updated.";
            string IOSpostData =
          "{\"data\": {\"contentTitle\":\"" + IOScontentTitle + "\", " +
                       "\"message\": \"" + status + "\"}}";
```

In debugger i can see below code generated for the above.

```
"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"{\"data\": {\"contentTitle\":\"Lease status updated.\", \"message\": \"CompletedStatusmessage\"}}\",\"badge\":20,\"sound\":\"mailsent.wav\"},\"acme1\":\"bar\",\"acme2\":42}"
```

I am not able to send messages. May i know am i missing anything in the above code? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: strmsgbody is json that isn't escaped. I end up with `"alert": "{" data ": {" contentTitle ":" Lease status updated.", " message ": " CompletedStatusmessage "}}",` if I take your debugger output.

Comment: Thanks for your comment John. what should i change in the above code?

Comment: I'm a little hazy on Apple notifications since we send ours through a third party, but I think you need to change `alert\":\"" + strmsgbody + "\",` to `alert\":" + strmsgbody + ",`. I'd recommend just building the data using classes in C# and then serializing to JSON, to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payload for getting push notifications on iOS devices should be

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Lease status updated.",
            "body" : "CompletedStatusmessage"
        },
        "badge" : 20,
        "sound" : "mailsent.wav "
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}
```

and what you are sending

```
    "{
    "aps ":{
      " alert ":" {
        "data": {
            "contentTitle": "Lease status updated.",
            "message": "CompletedStatusmessage"
        }
    }

",
" badge ":20,
" sound ":"mailsent.wav "},
" acme1 ":" bar ",
  " acme2 ":42
}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment swetansh kumar. can you share me one sample code for the above correct format?

Comment: hi Swetansh kumar. This is i have. payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + strmsgbody + "\",\"badge\":" + totunreadmsg.ToString() + ",\"sound\":\"mailsent.wav\"},\"acme1\":\"bar\",\"acme2\":42}";

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole your payload contains badge as String. Kindly make it Integer.

Comment: changing the badge value to int will make the payload correct.